# Transcoding and Adaptive Failover (Google) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, google, us20130272374, transcoding

Title: **Scalable, live transcoding with support for adaptive streaming and failover**

Assignee: **Google**

Publication Number: [US20130272374](http://www.google.com/patents/us20130272374)

Search for Prior art using: [Google Prior Art Finder](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20130272374#c=0&d1&d2=04%2F11%2F2012&t=1failover.1input%20streams.1pipelines.0support.0support%20for%20adaptive.0parallel%20pipelines.0adaptive%20streaming.0transcoding.0main%20stream.0segments.)

It seems like there is prior art for the basic idea, which more or less amounts to:

1. Find a keyframe and/or scene change within a given timestamp range, and split at this point.
2. Encode all N chunks in parallel with slightly overlapping bits, and at different qualities.
3. Recombine these chunks (either concat, or via HLS or DASH).

> Claim 1. A system, comprising:
>
> - A memory that stores computer executable components;
> - A processor that executes the following computer executable components stored in the memory:
> - A segment identification component that identifies segment boundaries within an interval of input streams for a plurality of transcoding pipelines;
> - A transcoding component that transcodes the input streams of the plurality of transcoding pipelines; and
> - A segmentation component that segments the input streams into equivalent chunks based on the segment boundaries identified, wherein the input streams include different transcode qualities.

Anyone even slightly familiar with digital video could think of this, and I have indeed implemented something like this myself (perhaps I can submit prior art?).

There are also things like:

http://omion.dyndns.org/x264farm/x264farm.html

which long predate this.

[image]

Looking for specific Prior Art references below **predating 4/11/12** which can be provided to the USPTO through Ask Patents.

Comment: The document in question is an application for a patent, not a granted patent.

Answer (score 1):

[This one with a priority date in 2008](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2009119888A1?cl=en&dq=parallel%20video%20transcoding&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Sd1aU5vdMeXu2AWcoYGwBg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA) seems to fit the bill, at least on the parallel nature of it:

> A method for decoding a video bitstream is disclosed. The method comprises: entropy decoding a first portion(112-1) of a video bitstream(52), wherein first portion(112-1) of video bitstream is associated with a video frame(110), thereby producing a first portion(112-1) of decoded data; entropy decoding a second portion(112-2) of video bitstream(52), wherein second portion(112-2) of video bitstream(52) is associated with video frame(110), thereby producing a second portion(112-2) of decoded data, wherein entropy decoding second portion(112-2) of video bitstream(52) is independent of entropy decoding first portion(112-1) of video bitstream(52); and reconstructing a first portion(112-1) of video frame(110) associated with video bitstream(52) using first portion(112-1) of decoded data and second portion(112-2) of decoded data.